# How to use select into statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert records from `Table1` and `Table2` into `Table3` and my `Table3` has Two columns:

```
studentId
subjectId
```

And I want to insert these 2 values from `Table1`(contains 1000 student Id's) and From `Table2`(contains 5 subjects). To achieve that I have used following query but it gave me error

Query:

```
INSERT INTO StudentSubject(studentId,subjectId)
SELECT studentId FROM Table1 UNION SELECT subjectId FROM Table2
```

But I got this error message:

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: Do you want to assign those 5 subjects to every student: 5 subjects x 1000 students = 5000 rows ?

Comment: yes, exactly the same

Comment: I think you should have a 2nd table that links subjects and students instead.

Comment: Then, you could use CROSS JOIN. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT into StudentSubject(studentId,subjectId)
SELECT a.studentId,b.subjectId 
FROM Table1 a CROSS JOIN Table2 b
```